# Waiting for Firebase RTDB to update state

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I am creating a data context for my react native app. There is an array of property objects in a firebase node and the aim is to pull this data into the app on load and provide that data throughout the app. I have a loader that shows if the loading state is true and should only be false if the data has been successfully pulled from firebase.

The issue I am having is the Loader ends before all the data is called and then the properties are not shown on the home page of the app until i refresh the app again.

Below is the code for the app:

```
import { onValue, ref } from 'firebase/database'
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { projectDatabase } from '../../config'
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth'

export const DataContext = React.createContext()

const DataLayer = ({ children }) => {
    const { userCredentials: user } = useAuth() //get user data
    const [company, setCompany] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [properties, setProperties] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const userRef = ref(projectDatabase, 'users/' + user.uid + '/company');
        onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {
          setCompany(snapshot.val());
          const propertiesRef = ref(projectDatabase, 'providers/' + snapshot.val() + '/properties');
          onValue(propertiesRef, (propertiesSnapshot) => {
        //  console.log(propertiesSnapshot.val())
            setProperties(propertiesSnapshot.val());
            setLoading(false);
          });
        });


    }, [])

    return (
        <DataContext.Provider
            value={{
            properties:properties,
                company: company,
                loading: loading,
                userEnquiries:userEnquiries,
                chatId:chatId,
                acceptedBookings:acceptedBookings    
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default DataLayer
```

Is there a way to make the call to the firebase RTDB complete BEFORE the loading is resolved as false or do i just do a useEffect call to every page the data is needed? For context the array has 200 properties.

I would really appreciate any help I can get. I love firebase and would really want this to work.

Comment: that still doesnt work here. It is also best practice I am sure. Firebase has got to have a way of causing the asynchronous onValue call wait until it is resolved.